# Do the gods Ameteratsu and Inari have any consorts?

Tags: japanese, shinto

The goddess Ameteratsu is the Japanese Sun goddess and the queen of the deities of the Shinto pantheon. Inari is the Japanese deity of agriculture and food.Both of these gods are very popular in the Shinto pantheon and I am wondering if they have any consorts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amateratsu is traditionnaly the spouse of her very own brother Tsukuyomi. You can check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaterasu).
In case of Inari he was married with Ukemochi and after Tsukuyomi slain her he married Mitama (Uga-no-Mitama).
Note also that Inari is vastly renown to have both a male and female form and those spouses are much more the "traditionally in some myths" spouses than the definitives wifes. Some other traditions mention that Ukemochi and Mitama are a form of Inari.

Comment: Inari has either 3 or 5 forms depending on which of the ancient texts you read. The three forms are a young beautiful woman, an old man and a genderless one.